# Mysql master-master temporarily unreachable, lots of 'Sleep' queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have a working MySQL master-master setup. I noticed that sometimes, when one of the servers becomes unreachable, the other fills up with queries in `Sleep` status.

I don't know what the queries are about because the `State` column is empty. I enabled slowqueries log but couldn't find anything useful in it.

As soon as the other server becomes reachable, the queries slowly disappear in a matter of seconds and everything returns normal.

Both the servers run the same MySQL version (5.6.38). Where can I check in order to understand what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

SLEEPing connections are connections for which complete data hasn't yet been received. They are often used for applications to improve the speed of queries so depending on the application may be being caused by that but in the context of replication it's likely to be because you have a lag in processing, which could be due to large amounts of data being replicated or complex queries being processed.
If you have a slow or sporadic connection then that will be the issue and really it's MySQL doing its job properly.

Comment: Thank you, I solved. It wasn't MySQL related, anyway. I'm going to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. It wasn't MySQL related.

In fact, some poorly programmed PHP webpages couldn't reach an external mail server, and they didn't close the MySQL connections until phpmailer didn't timeout.